# Active Directory The object already exists using SetPassword and new object []{}

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm hoping someone can explain this to me because I am at my wits end trying to resolve an issue I am having.

The error I am receiving is, "The object already exists." whenever I am trying to run our ResetPassword function. The weird thing is I ONLY receive this error if the user account has had their password reset before. If I either create a new account with a new password, or search for a user in the database that has not had the ResetPassword function called on their account, then it will let me call this function once. Note: On this one time it lets me run the function the password does get reset. Any account that has already run ResetPassword will prompt the object already exists error.

```
    public static void ResetPassword(DirectoryEntry User, string password)
    {

        User.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
        User.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0x0000; //unlock account
        int val = (int)User.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
        User.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val & ~0x2; //Enable account 

        User.CommitChanges();

        Logs.CreateLogEntry("Reset password", User);

        User.Close();
    }
```

As you can see, we are passing in a DirectoryEntry user, along with a generated new password. We are using an anonymous login on the backend of our IIS website to have admin credentials high enough to use SetPassword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide credentials of a user in AD that has admin privileges to reset passwords.

```
public static void ResetPassword(string username, string password)
{
  string adminUser = "YourAdminUserIdInAD";
  string adminPass = "YourAdminUserPasswordInAD";
  string ldapString = "LDAP://YourLDAPString";
  DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapString , adminUser, adminPass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
  DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry) {
                    SearchRoot = dEntry, 
                    Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(cn=" + username + "))"
  };
  var directoryEntry = deSearch.FindOne();

  directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
  directoryEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0x0000; //unlock account
  int val = (int)directoryEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
  directoryEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val & ~0x2;
  directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
  Logs.CreateLogEntry("Reset password", User);
  directoryEntry.Close();
}
```